# Ajax submit and get invalid character error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC, When I tried to key in `<HTML>` in text field and submit form it prompt me *parse error and invalid character*.

But when I tried to key in `<222>` or `HTML>`, the form submitted without problem.

It is weird and I tried to encode it before submitting but I still get the same result, anyone have an idea?

Below is the code:

```
$('#form1').bind('submit', function (e) {                
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        iframe: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function (e) {

        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
```

Here are the form submit

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("TestSet", "test", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "form1" }))
```

Here are the controller

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public FileUploadJsonResult test(testViewModel testvm)
    {
    }
```

I did tested to

```
  $('#form1').bind('submit', function (e) {                
    e.preventDefault(); 
     var data = $("#frmTaskSet").serializeArray();
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        iframe: true,
        dataType: 'json',
         //data: JSON.stringify(data),
        or 
        //data: encodeURIComponent(data), 
        error: function (e) {

        },
        success: function (data) {

        }
```

Update: 
  I had shrink the problem area, I try to key in `<ABC>` or `<ABC` into the text field and pass this value to controller then it hit the error but weird thing is if I pass using ABC>  or <123> it successful without problem.

```
           var task1 = $("#text1").val().toString();
           var encode1 =  escapeHTML(task1);
           var encode2 =  encodeURIComponent(task1);
           var encode3 = $("<div>").text(task1).html();


            alert(encode1); //&lt;ABC&gt;
            alert(encode2); //%3CABC%3E
            alert(encode3); //&lt;ABC&gt;

                $(this).ajaxSubmit({
                    iframe: true,
                    dataType: 'json',
                     data: { Name: encode4 },
                   //contentType: "application/json",
                    error: function (e,errordata, errorObject) {

                    },
```

ERROR I get is parse error , and syntaxError:Invalid Character, it happen before I post to the server side.

Comment: `ajaxSubmit` must be from a plugin (jQuery form plugin?). Anyway, you say you tried to encode it, but *how*?

Comment: Exactly where does the error occur?  Before posting or server side?  You've marked this `model-view-controller` but there's no mention of the pattern - did you mean [asp.net-mvc]

Comment: Hi freedomn-m, thanks for responding, the error occur before posting to server, yes I am using asp.net-mvc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASP.Net MVC does not support user to enter html tags. To achieve this you can use  `ValidateInput` attribute and `AllowHtml` attribute.

You can use this at controller level or action level

Example

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
 return View();
 }         
 // Do your code
}
```

Also you can use the `AllowHtml` attribute for particular property

```
public class Demo
{
 [Required]
 [Display(Name = "Title")]
 public string Title{ get; set; }

 [AllowHtml]
 [Required]
 [Display(Name = "Description")]
 public string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

For more information visit [this article](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/2NH8130313-Html-submission-by-ValidateInput-and-AllowHtml-attribute-in-MVC4.html)